# UsesWP plugin prevent blocks notification mail for a new user

Tags: email, notifications

On a fresh-brand-new-blank wp, I've installed "UsersWP plugin" and it works well.
But it sounds like as soon as the plugin is activated, the mail to the admin for notifying him a new user is created, seems not working **when I use WP admin panel to create a new user**.

- I've try "Email & Log Check" plugin which send me a mail correctly.
- The notification mail for the new user is sent and arrived well.
- Everything is check in the plugin to send notif'admin email.
- My host doesn't block my mail, and no-one in the spam.
- I try using "brevo" a SMTP plugin, no change.

1. So, after long time to understand the plugin's core code in vain, I would like to know if you've got some idea to share. In another way, what could prevent this behaviour in a plugin?
2. And I would like to know which hook is used to send the email for the admin after a new user creation.

Thanks a loooot ! Nicolas.

Answer (score 1):

Third party plugins are off-topic here, so you'll need to address your main question to the plugin developer. Your second question is generic enough that I'll provide an answer here:

> And I would like to know which hook is used to send the email for the
> admin after a new user creation.

The user notifications are sent by the `wp_send_new_user_notifications()` function, which is hooked in the following places in `wp-includes/default-filters.php`:

```
add_action( 'register_new_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications' );
add_action( 'edit_user_created_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications', 10, 2 );
```

On multisite they are hooked in `wp-includes/default-filters.php`:

```
add_action( 'network_site_new_created_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications' );
add_action( 'network_site_users_created_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications' );
add_action( 'network_user_new_created_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications' );
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll already send a mail to the support and I will dig the way you're talking about.